# Add element to array via for loop and then return the last item

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a for loop in which I'm detecting how many checkboxes have been checked. I'm trying to push the results to an array and then get the very last item in that array. 
This is my code so far.

```
function updateParentLabel(parentList) {
var label = parentList.parent().find('label:first');
var checked = parentList.find(':checked');

var count = 0;
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++){
    if(checked){
        count++;
    }else {
        count--;
    }
    result.push(count);
    console.log(result);
}

label.append(count);
```

}

So far so good but, then I've tried this which doesn't work:

```
result.pop(); //returns []
```

Comment: `parentList` is a jQuery object? Do you get `result` logged to the console? Notice, that `result` is a local variable in `updateParentLabel()` and can't be seen  outside of the function. Also `if (checked)` will always pass in your code.

Comment: Run out of the letters from the keyboard? Please answer the questions...

Comment: Hi. Thanks! Sry for my late reply. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much easier way to detect whether a checkbox has been checked and act accordingly, which makes the for loop unnecessary. In essence this is what I came up with.

```
function updateParentLabel(parentList) {
var label = parentList.parent().find('label:first');
var checked_length = parentList.find(':checked').length;

if (checked_length !== 0) {
    label.append(span);
}
else {
    label.find('span').remove();
}
```

}